# Issue with connecting Printer device

Tags: java

I was getting below error when i run the application without connecting the printer device(it's configured) and application is getting freeze .

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: openDevice
Opening the Printer deivce
    at acr.device.port.GenericUSB.openDevice(Native Method)
    at acr.device.port.GenericUSB.open(GenericUSB.java:91)
    at acr.device.DevicePort.open(DevicePort.java:41)
    at acr.device.DeviceDriver.open(DeviceDriver.java:136)
    at acr.device.DevMgr$OpenPrinter.run(DevMgr.java:515)
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Are you getting same error when you attach printer?

Comment: no, it's work fine when it's connected. but our new requirement is application should work normally when printer is configured but not connected or off line.